# Return common results in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have a many to many relationship, agents that can have many properties, and vice versa, defined in a in a junction table, how would I query the "top" agents (an agent who has at least two properties in common with two other agents.)

`agent_properties`

| agent_id | property_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 4 | 6 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 5 | 5 |
| 6 | 4 |
| 6 | 6 |

### Example:

Agent 1 (propr1, propr2, propr3),

Agent 2 (propr2, propr3),

Agent 3 (propr1, propr3, propr5)

Agent 4 (propr3, propr4, propr6)

Agent 5 (propr1, propr2, propr5)

Agent 6 (propr4, propr6)

So the query should return **Agent 1, Agent 3, Agent 5**

Agent 1 (he has at least two properties in common with agent2
and agent3).

Agent 3 (he has at least two properties in common with agent1
and agent5).

Agent 5 (he has at least two properties in common with agent1
and agent3).

Comment: Agent1 has 2 common properties with Agent3 and Agent5. Is this your requirement, or do you want all returned  agents to have at least 2 common properties with each other?

Comment: @forpas The requirement is for an agent to have at least two properties in common with at least 2 other agents. I've updated the question to explain the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> an agent who has at least two properties in common with two other agents.

Count the number of agents per property (using window functions).  Then take the agents where there are at least two properties with two agents:

```
select agent_id
from (select ap.*,
             count(*) over (partition by property_id) as num_agents
      from agent_properties ap
     ) ap
where num_agents > 2   -- properties that are shared have more than two agents
group by agent_id
having count(*) >= 2;  -- at least two properties that are shared
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cce1e12758318e0309f353559c1eeacd) is a db<>fiddle.

EDIT:

Oh, I see.  I was going down the wrong path looking at properties first and then agents.

You want a self join with aggregation to calculate the number of properties in common between two agents.  Then you want limits in that aggregation:

```
select agent_id
from (select ap1.agent_id, ap2.agent_id as agent_id2, count(*) as properties_in_common
      from agent_properties ap1 join
           agent_properties ap2
           on ap1.property_id = ap2.property_id and ap1.agent_id <> ap2.agent_id
      group by ap1.agent_id, ap2.agent_id
     ) aa
where properties_in_common >= 2
group by agent_id
having count(*) >= 2
```

Comment: This query returns 1,3,4,5. Instead of 1,3,5, I'm looking to return agents who have at least 2 properties in common with at least 2 other agents.

Comment: @TonySala Gordon gave you some help. if you need to solve that problem of yours, probably the best way is you come up with some answer yourself, in the first place. Best regards.

Comment: @TonySala . . . I misunderstood the question.  It is a good question and even well explained.  The latest edit should do what you want.